# Separate PHP error logs and system logs with nginx for each virtualhost

Tags: php, nginx, error-log

How can I set up NGINX to log separately system error and PHP error messages for every virtual host. 
Somehow I should overwrite the global php.ini error_log value for each virtual host.
What I found:

```
    server {
       server_name some-server.com;
       access_log /var/log/nginx/some-server.access.log;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/some-server.error.log info;
       root /var/websites/some-server/;
       fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=\"/var/log/nginx/some-server.php-error.log\"";
    }
```

However file parmissions are OK, this solution is not working!

Comment: Have you found out in the meantime why the configuration was not accepted? How did you verify the file permissions are OK?

Answer (score 1):

You should create separate virtual hosts. The best practice told that each virtual host error and access log file should be equivalent with domain name. For example if your domain is `example.com` your log file should be `example.com.log`
Here is a full documentation [how to create](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) virtual host.
 Add below 2 lines with your domain name (change some-server) in `server` block

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/some-server.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/some-server.error.log info;
```

Comment: Hi! I know how to create virtual hosts. I want a separate PHP error log and a server error log file for each virtualhost, but my server takes in count only the error_log directive in php.ini. This means all PHP errors are going in one file (not separately for every domain)

Comment: You needn't change php.ini for changing error log file for each VH. You should specify the log file in each VH.

Comment: As I know error_log directive specifies the system (nginx server error) log file for a VH. I need another log file, for PHP error logs too (for each VH)

Comment: Yes, all right. See above answer: `The best practice told that each virtual host error and access log file should be equivalent with domain name`

Comment: This way: error_log /var/log/nginx/some-server.error.log info; all error msg. (nginx+PHP error) will go in one file for that domain.